# Tengo un problema con mi ajax cuando hago una peticion y no entra a mi servicio en mi asp.net

Tags: ajax, asp.net, servicio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenas, Jean Franco, bienvenido al sitio. En primer lugar, deberías pegar tu código como texto formateado. En segundo, en tu primero imagen se aprecia que tu página ASP está generando un error al intentar ejecutarse. Copia ese error aquí también para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. "Tengo un problema" no es un título descriptivo. El código y los mensajes de error siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes.